# Xml parsing not working with Swedish Chrs

Tags: java, xml, parsing, locale

I am trying to parse the following xml to punycode but it's not working (i have tried setting the encoding differently).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<domain index="1" domainname="teståbel.nu">

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<domain index="1" domainname="teståbel.nu">


public void setDomainName(String domainName) {
        this.domainName = java.net.IDN.toUnicode(domainName);
```

When I run the setDomain() everything is set correctly.

I have run this on my machine, Windows 7 with Local set to Swedish, and it fails. Then I tested it on another machine with windows XP with Local set to English(US) set to  and it Works.

So my conlusion is that the coding is working but my environment is wrong, anyone know how to fix this? Can i run my JVM with some parameter or something?

Comment: Is your XML file *really* ISO-8859-1 encoded? Look at it in a binary editor and update your question with what bytes are in the file.

Comment: When you open the XML file with a hex editor, what is the byte sequence you see at `å`?

Comment: Chances are that you are looking at `Windows-1252`, which is similar - and by all means preferred - to `ISO-8859-1`, but it's not exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okej so I found the answer, I need to run my JVM with he following option:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS : -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

Comment: Usually (that is, if you build and use your XML with the appropriate DOM API), you do not have to worry about these things. The fact that you have to set file encoding as a Java option means you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That the result depends on the locale of your machine suggests that you are reading the xml file using the default charset of the jvm. The correct way would be to let the xml parser figure out the encoding. This usually means to use an `InputStream` instead of a `Reader` when parsing the document.

You did not show the part where you actually parse the file but I guess you are creating a `FileReader` or `InputStreamReader` without specifying the charset, just use a `FileInputStream` instead.